# Django-invitation, invite template gives a DoesNotExist type error

Tags: python, django, invite

I am using the app django-register and django-invitation.

The page `url/accounts/invite/` shows the form to invite someone. When I enter an email address and click "send invitation" I get a DoesNotExist exception with the exception value being

```
Site matching query does not exist.
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. It might be worth mentioning that when I use the register app to register an account, it works fine and an email is said to the person registering.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `settings.py` like the [example](http://code.larlet.fr/django-invitation/src/127ac49785f6/examples/invitation_project/settings.py?at=default) given:

```
SITE_ID = 1
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ...
)
```

Or simply I recommand you check all your files under the `django-invatation` templates directory, remove or replace all tags including `{{ site }}`, if you don't need it.

Comment: I applied the changed, but still get the error:

Exception Type: DoesNotExist

Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.

Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 366

Comment: @user1627762 Have you added site in admin?

Comment: As in the admin.py file? No, I didn't think I needed to * currently tying then will update, thanks :)*

Comment: Did you mean /admin/sites/site/ or admin.py?

Comment: @user1627762 I mean /admin/sites/site/ , if you do not use site, I recommand the second method.